# running exponential decay with addition?

Tags: python, exponential, cumulative-sum, decrement

The formula for exponential decay is :

```
 np.exp(-(t/n))
```

where **t** is the time step and **n** is coef to control how fast to decay.
What I'm looking for is **running**-function where I calculate the value at every step manually and also the ability to add values during decay.

How would I do that ?

I also found another formula :  `(1-percent)^t`

---

```
 def decay(val, rate): return val * np.exp(-rate)

In [84]: decay(1,1/10.)
Out[84]: 0.905

In [85]: decay(0.905,1/10.)
Out[85]: 0.819

In [86]: decay(0.819,1/10.)
Out[86]: 0.741

In [88]: np.exp(-1/10.)
Out[88]: 0.905

In [89]: np.exp(-2/10.)
Out[89]: 0.819

In [90]: np.exp(-3/10.)
Out[90]: 0.741
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a math question.

Comment: it is a running exp decay .. i.e. programmer question ... i.e. convert math formula to algorithm !!!

Comment: why dont you make a loop and add the `decay` function returns? if you are looking for explicit formula for the sum then yes that is a math question.

Answer (score 0):

Could I suggest using an array to evaluate at every timestep *t*? You would need to edit your function to include the decay constant *n*.

```
def decay(t, A, n):
    return A*np.exp(-t/n)

t = np.linspace(0, 10, 256)

initial = 1
rate = 10

value = decay(t, initial, rate)
```

*value* would then be an array for the value of your decaying function at every *t*.

Comment: thanks ... no i figured out what I needed .. i dont need a  trail, just keep one value that is updated and decays, but can be changed in midfly :)

Comment: @sten, please update with your answer. Others would benefit more from this page with it.